# Change raspberry pi sleep time

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, touchscreen

I recently bought the 7" touchscreen for my raspberry pi B 3 running Raspbian and and wanting to use it as a wall mounted display for a smart home project. However I would like the touchscreen to "sleep" or turn off sooner than the time that it's set at now (I think 30 mins but I am not sure.) If there is a way to shorten that time and also retain the ability to "wake" the screen when touched would be amazing.

The second question would be, is there a way programmatically to "wake" the display? For example, if a notification shows up the screen would wake to show that.

Comment: If I remember correctly it should be an option in `/etc/kbd/config`

Answer (score 2):

The commands to directly turn OFF and ON the screen are.

OFF

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

ON

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

You might need to run these with sudo e.g.

```
sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
```